# Drawing an image on the screen during initramfs

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, boot, framebuffer, initrd

I'm trying to draw an error image during initramfs on a base ubuntu 18.04 image.

My issue is that when I write the image directly into `/dev/fb0` The card only appears to redraw areas of the screen the are being changed by the console output.

Is there a way to force the card to redraw the full framebuffer?  Or a better way to go about displaying an image during initramfs?  This image is an error image that will cause the init process to halt and be displayed indefinitely.

here is an example of what the screen looks like when I try and draw on the framebuffer and then hit enter a few times.

[image]t